# Trying to parse JSON objects to HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using a jquery method to load JSON objects from the database. Then, I would want to display the record row by row in a HTML table. As can be seen in my JS file, I have tried to use a for and for each loop to loop through the data records but none of them are working apparently. My table seems to not display anything on the table or even error on result/ console log. However, there are data in my network log.

The json record in the network log is:

```
data: [
      0:{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "type": "Client"
      },
      1:{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Damen",
        "type": "Agent"
      },
      2:{
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Aiden",
        "type": "Admin"
      }
    ]
```

The HTML page is:

```
<table id="report" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>           
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>         
        </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    app.viewReport();      
</script>
```

My JS page is:

```
viewReport : function() {
               $.ajax({
                url: "/FIS/back-api/client/transaction/view",
                dataType: "json",
                method : 'GET',
                success : function(data){
                 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].id+ "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].name+ "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].type+ "</td>");  
                    $('#report tbody').append(tr);
                }               
                }           
                /*$.each(data,function(i,item){
                            $('#report tr.odd').remove();
                            $("#report tbody").append(
                                "<tr>"
                                    +"<td>"+item.id+"</td>"
                                    +"<td>"+item.name+"</td>"
                                    +"<td>"+item.type+"</td>"                                                       
                                +"</tr>" )
                            })  
                }*/
    })
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John , your JSON is invalid , this is the closest valid JSON i prepared from sample you shared above :

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "type": "Client"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Damen",
    "type": "Agent"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Aiden",
    "type": "Admin"
  }
]
```

Notice that for an array of objects  `0 : {}` format is invalid, so when you query it in a loop you're not receiving any result.

**Incorrect :**

```
   0:{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "type": "Client"
      }
```

**Correct :**

```
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "type": "Client"
      }
```

**How to validate your JSON**

Following sites will help you verify your json :

[jsonlint](http://zaa.ch/jsonlint/)

[jsoneditoronline](http://jsoneditoronline.org/)

**Answer**

Re-generate your `JSON` and then proceed as indicated in other answers.

Also , i would advice against parsing the result as string ! In my humble opinion, the proper way to do this is to return a valid `json` from Backend/server

Comment: I am basically using a foreach ( $transactions as $i => $transaction ) and returning it as $transactions in the backend. So you are saying i have to modify my backend code somehow?

Comment: Yes ! what you are receiving right now will not work , moreover doing this in backend is straightforward , search for **serialize an object to json** in whatever backend technology you are using'

Answer (score 0):

try to append it like this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var htm = '';
    htm += '<tr>';
    htm += "<td>" + data[i].id.toString() + "</td>";
    htm += "<td>" + data[i].name.toString() + "</td>";
    htm += "<td>" + data[i].type.toString() + "</td>";  
    htm += '</tr>';
    $('#report tbody').append(htm);
 }
```

Comment: even that doesn't solve the issue. My table is still empty but my network log is displaying those records

Comment: nope, I tried the same one, and still it is not appending anything

Comment: but when I try to replace (data[i].id) with a number or a string, it will display

Comment: @JohnWick maybe you should parse the data to string, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Process your JSON data correctly like Winnie said in another answer of this question. Then you have not defined table row correctly.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('#report tbody').append(
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(data[i].id),
            $('<td>').text(data[i].name),
            $('<td>').text(data[i].type)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: nothing is displayed, the table seems to be not appending anything

Comment: Did you run it inside your for loop? Anyway, updated answer

Comment: yea I did the exact same, it's not displaying. It is just empty with no error in console log

Comment: but when I try to replace (data[i].id) with a number or a string, it will display

Comment: Okay, another problem is with your  json. I overlooked that at first place. It should be array of objects like [{id: 1, name: 'John', type: 'client'}] and so on. Like @Winnie said

Answer (score 0):

Your data array is having keys, which is incorrect json format, If its an array it should look like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "type": "Client"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Damen",
        "type": "Agent"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Aiden",
        "type": "Admin"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "type": "Client"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Damen",
    "type": "Agent"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Aiden",
    "type": "Admin"
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var body = document.getElementById("tableBody");
  var row = body.insertRow();
  for (var item in data[i]) {
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = data[i][item];
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```